# `OperatorPrecedenceParser` with recursive term - FParsec

Tags: f#, parsec, fparsec

I have a parser implemented with monadic links, something like that:

```
let rec p1 = parse {}
and p2 = parse {}
and p3 = parse {}

and p = p1 <|> p2 <|> p3

and document = spaces >>? many p .>>? spaces
```

I would like to implement an arithmetic expression parser that takes as term `p`:

```
let opParser = new OperatorPrecedenceParser<_, _, _> ()
// Adding operators
let term = p
opParser.TermParser <- spaces >>? term .>>? spaces
```

Except that I would like analyzers who use `p` to be able to use arithmetic expressions as well. So I do this:

```
let opParser = new OperatorPrecedenceParser<_, _, _> ()
// Adding operators

let rec p1 = parse {}
and p2 = parse {}
and p3 = parse {}

and p = p1 <|> p2 <|> p3 <|> (opParser.ExpressionParser)

let term = p
opParser.TermParser <- spaces >>? term .>>? spaces
```

The problem is that it causes a stack overflow at runtime.

How can we avoid it while respecting the "contract"?